# Integrate Netty server with Akka?

Tags: java, network-programming, netty, akka, actor

I see that Netty is a framework for building asynchronous network software. I'm wondering if there is a way to integrated the server-side with Akka such that, any time a request is received from a Netty client, an Akka "actor" thread on the server picks it up and responds to it asynchronously. Is there any value to this type of integration (scaling, fault tolerance, etc.) on the server, or does Netty's asynchronous nature already provide everything that the server would need (from a threading standpoint)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we are doing this in several places within Akka, e.g. in the [Test Conductor](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.3.2/akka-multi-node-testkit/src/main/scala/akka/remote/testconductor/Conductor.scala#L244) for our multi-JVM tests. There is also the [Akka IO](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.2/java/io.html) package which contains our own implementation for offering TCP and UDP connectivity to actors.

Comment: Thanks @Roland Kuhn (+1) - so is it that the real advantage to integrating Netty with Akka is to provide network access to Actor clusters/groups? Meaning, if I have a cluster of Actors doing some arbitrary task, `Task1`, and perhaps I want to make them available to some client application, I could use Netty to connect the client to the Actor cluster? Is that a fair assessment? Thanks again!

Comment: You could do that, yes.

Comment: Thanks again @Roland (+1) - judging by your answer I'm guessing that my use case above *isn't* a normal use case for integrating Netty and Akka? If so, what would be a normal use case?